# Conversion from LocalDB (.mdf) file to SQL Server Express .mdf file and reverse process

Tags: sql-server-express, localdb

Since we need to move around our database a lot (like update it with new Rows which are generated by code and then update it prod db and reverse process). SQL Server CE, being a file based system was very helpful.

We would like to upgrade to use SQL Server Local Db but at the same time, it has limitations of use with IIS (though possible with `AttacheDbFile`). In this regard, since LocalDb is more or less a version of SQL Server Express, would it be possible to use our SQL Server LocalDB `.mdf` in our development environment and then copy them in prod but use by attaching to a SQL Server Express instance?

If yes, what additional thing, we need to do make it possible?

Also, we would like the reverse process to be worked out as well, mean detach the `.mdf` file and use it as LocalDb in development environment. I have read the great blog articles of 
Krzysztof Kozielczyk also but not have experimented much with LocalDb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LocalDB ***IS*** SQL Server Express (introduced with SQL Server 2012 Express), and the `.mdf` file is identical between LocalDB and SQL Server Express (and even a "full" SQL Server edition like Web, Standard or Enterprise Edition).

The only caveat is: you need to be using the same **versions** of those databases, since the file format is only identical amongst same versions, and can only be used amongst the same versions (e.g. 2012) - or it can be "upgraded" to the next newer version (e.g. you could move a database from LocalDB 2012 to a SQL Server 2014 Express once it's released) - but you can never **go back down** to an earlier version (you cannot take a LocalDB 2012 `.mdf` database file and attach it to a SQL Server 2008 version).

Comment: +1 @marc_s for confirming that .mdf file is of same format with the caveet of requirement of same version.  It seems to me from your answer that moving around db is quite possible as long as we use same version of these databases in different environment.

Comment: @James: yes, if you have the same version of SQL Server on all involved servers, then it's not an issue moving around. Going up to a newer version also isn't an issue - but there's no way back to an older version.